# Prove $A \setminus (A \setminus (A \setminus B)) = A \setminus B.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\renewcommand{\backslash}{\setminus}$

The question is as is in the title. I am able to show that $A \setminus (A \setminus (A \setminus B)) \subseteq A \setminus B$ but I am stuck on showing that $A \setminus B \subseteq  A \setminus (A \setminus (A \setminus B))$.

Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions will help.

Here is what I have so far:

$\textbf{Proof:}$

To show that $A \backslash (A \backslash (A \backslash B)) = A \backslash B$, we need to show that $A \backslash (A \backslash (A \backslash B)) \subseteq A \backslash B$ and $A \backslash B \subseteq  A \backslash (A \backslash (A \backslash B))$.

We first show that $A \backslash (A \backslash (A \backslash B)) \subseteq A \backslash B$.

Let $a \in A \backslash (A \backslash (A \backslash B))$.

$\implies a \in A \cap (A \backslash (A \backslash B))^c$

$\implies a \in A \cap (A \cap (A \backslash B)^c)^c$

$\implies a \in A \cap (A \cap (A \cap B^c)^c)^c$

$\implies a \in A \cap (A^c \cup (A \cap B^c))$

$\implies a \in A \cap ((A^c \cup A) \cap (A^c \cup B^c))$

$\implies a \in A \cap (U \cap (A^c \cup B^c))$

$\implies a \in A \cap (A^c \cup B^c)$

$\implies a \in (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B^c)$

$\implies a \in \emptyset \cup (A \cap B^c)$

$\implies a \in (A \cap B^c)$

$\implies a \in (A \backslash B)$

Next, we show that $A \backslash B \subseteq  A \backslash (A \backslash (A \backslash B))$.

Let $a \in A \backslash B$.

$\implies a \in A \backslash (A \backslash B)^c$

$\implies a \in A \backslash (A \backslash (A \backslash B)^c)^c$

$\implies a \in A \backslash (A \cap (A \backslash B))^c$

$\implies a \in A \backslash (A^c \cup (A \backslash B)^c)$

$\implies a \in A \backslash (A^c \cup (A^c \cup B))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can reverse the whole thing, i.e. if in the first half you simply change every $\Rightarrow$ into a $\Leftrightarrow$, you're there!

In fact, with algebra it's pretty simple:

$$A \setminus (A \setminus (A \setminus B)) = $$

$$A \cap (A \cap (A \cap B^c)^c)^c =$$

$$ A \cap (A^c \cup (A \cap B^c) =$$

$$ (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap A \cap B^c) =$$

$$ \emptyset \cup (A \cap B^c) =$$

$$ A\setminus B$$

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but you could simplify notation quite a bit by writing $C = A \setminus B$ and showing that $A \setminus (A \setminus C) = C$ for any set $C \subset A$.

Note that if $D \subset A$, then $x \in D$ if and only if $x \notin A \setminus D$, and $x \notin D$ if and only if $x \in A \setminus D$

So, let $C \subset A$.  Then
$$x \in C \iff x \notin A \setminus C \iff x \in A \setminus (A \setminus C)$$
by applying the preceding remark to $D = C$ and $D = A \setminus C$, respectively.